# 12VDC Switching to 17VDC high amerage

Tags: power-supply, buck, 12v, peltier, diy

It's been years since my undergrad work as an EE. I am a physicist and medical researcher now, but, as a startup, we all take on anything we can.

Let's face it... 12VDC high current PSU's are cheap. But when we need a different voltage we don't want to buy custom (expensive) and typical bucking isn't high enough in current.

Right now, we need to take the two 12VDC @ 150A supplies we have and make one 17 VDC and the other 34 VDC.

Off the shelf, what is available? Could we build SIMPLE circuits with MOSFETS (if so, what is the circuit diagram?)

We've also read that inverters (DC to AC mains) can generally be used in reverse. IE, supply 110/220VAC to the output as an imput, and the input with output the designed VDC input. This would be simple and cheap enough if true.

In all honesty, why can't we crack open a PC PSU and up the output voltage?

Many questions here. IE we are open to ideas to get non-standard VDC at high current.

Thanks,

- J

**____________________________________**

**From comments:**

The output current is currently 15.4A . VDC needed currently is 17 and 36.

Comment: Found this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076TTBKFG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1   

Will it work for 12VDC in from computer PSU and output the various voltages we need (limited to the 20A output, of course).

Comment: You still didn't specify the output current. How lucky do you feel about overvoltage on the caps if you adjusted the main regulator?

Comment: Apologies, Sunny: The output current is currently 15.4A . VDC needed currently is 17 and 36.  Assume you mean the caps in the PSU unit? If so, not too worried about it. They are donated for this educational science project by the NSF. Obviously we don't want to destroy, but science is science.

Comment: The board looks undersized . Buy spares and a high speed fan.

Comment: Yeah. That's the issue. At $33 each and it will only power one unit, it is crazy expensive.

What if we rectified the 220VAC with ripple capacitors using high amperage diodes then put the 17VDC, 15A units in series?

Comment: Some DC->AC Mains inverters intended for use in boats and RVs do include a high current charger, but I don't know how much, of any, circuitry is shared between the inverter and charger functions.  You can't take just any DC->AC inverter and run it "backwards" to use as a DC supply.  The 2000 W inverter/100 Amp charger I have on my boat cost over Can$2000.

Comment: $33 doesn’t sound high for a medical research R&D budget, but they are not made for harsh load switching and disconnect when active with intermittent inductive spikes.

Comment: This isn't a _great_ idea, but you could connect multiple power supplies together in series then regulate the voltage down to what you need. This would be cheaper than a boost solution.

Comment: Your much better starting high and bucking down, rather then starting low and boosting up with this level of power.